# Django Templates: External link with variable

Tags: html, django, django-templates

This link is an external site link, all solutions I found mention an internal link with static or variables

In the HTML

```
<a href="https://externalsite.com/page1/page2/assetId="/{{varID}}/">{{varName}}/a>
```

It always comes up with a spaces around varID. I tried Trimming the variable.
I tried escaping with /.

This is what it looks like in browser inspect

```
 <a href="https://externalsite.com/page1/page2/assetId="   1234  ">myAsset</a>
```

this is what the url is when you click on it

```
https://externalsite.com/page1/page2/assetId=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the quotes and slashes. Just put the variable inside the string.

**Edit**

```
<a href="https://externalsite.com/page1/page2/assetId={{varID}}">{{varName}}</a>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the anchor tag properly.
`<a href="https://externalsite.com/page1/page2/assetId={{varID}}">{{varName}}</a>`

Comment: ah I had a <mark> tag in there somewhere which was causing the extra space, knew it was silly error! but you're right I dont need the /